# GDAL's Gnomonic projection -- where do I set the elevation?

Tags: gdal, coordinate-system, elevation

I have an existing application that uses a Gnomonic projection where the elevation at the origin is added to the earth radius that is used in the projection calculations (6378137 plus elevation in m). I don't see anywhere to specify elevation/altitude in the `SpatialReference.SetGnomonic` method. Can I set some other attribute to achieve the same thing? Or can I modify the earth radius used by the projection?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The formulas for Gnomonic projection given by Snyder and http://mathworld.wolfram.com/GnomonicProjection.html don't take care about the elevation of the tangent point. Hence Proj.4 and GDAL have no parameter for it.

If you want to have the same results as your reference application, you might use `6378137 plus elevation` as an approximation. Anyway, using a sphere for the earth (and choosing some arbitrary [Earth radius](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Earth_radius)) already is an approximation.

Comment: Yes, adding elevation to the earth radius is what my old application does. My question was: how do that with GDAL?

Comment: On the command line, you can set `+R` to any value you want. There is no other way to add the elevation automatically. Programmatically, you may need to use `OGRSpatialReference::SetGeogCS` because the radius is part of the ellipsoid, not of the projection.

Comment: Calling `SetGeogCS` in addition to `SetGnomonic` did work for me. I was confused at first because I was using a well-known datum name. Using a custom datum name allowed a custom spheroid. `sr.SetGeogCS("Customized WGS84", "Custom Datum", "WGS84 Radius + Elevation",
    projection.Radius + projection.Origin.Altitude, double.PositiveInfinity, null, 0.0, null, 1.0);`